# UIAlertController in tableViewCell - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uitableview

I have a button in each cell in a `tableviewcell`. When the button is clicked, in the cell coding page I had an action which was working already. However I decided to let users confirm it before the action starts, so added an `UIAlertController` inside the action. The alert controller works fine in a `UIviewcontroller`, but in a `UItableviewcell` with the code below I got the error message: "does not have a member named `presentviewcontroller`". How can I make it work? My code is here. Thanks

```
@IBAction func followBtn_click(sender: AnyObject) {



        if title == "Following" {

            var refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Sure?", message: "Do you want to unfollow this person?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

            var query = PFQuery(className: "follow")

            query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
            query.whereKey("userToFollow", equalTo: usernameLbl.text!)

            var objects = query.findObjects()

            for object in objects! {

                object.delete()

            }

            }))

            refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                println("Cancel unfollow")
            }))

            self.presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

         /*  self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            when I use the above to make it run, the code runs but nothing happens and I get the warning below in the output area

             2015-07-02 08:57:22.978 MyLast[968:200872] Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7f849c04ed20> on <UINavigationController: 0x7f8499c69020> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!



          */



        }

        else {

            println(“rest will work”)
           /*   rest of the code */

        }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your tableview controller is in hierarchy of navigation controller or embed in UINavigationController. Because UIAlertView is deprecated in swift And there is a UIAlertViewController and whenever you require or to present Alert you must have a Controller Hierarchy.

You also can show ActionSheet using same code by little changes UIAlertControllerStyle is action sheet.

One another suggestions is once try with remove your handler code to nil

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
```

Comment: Hello, would the action sheet work in the uitableviewcell directly? How can I use it?

Comment: Here Complete code http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/action-sheet-tutorial-ios8-swift